# Random errors when embedding UILabel in UIView inside UIStackView

Tags: xcode, layout, constraints, uilabel, uistackview

One `UILabel` is placed directly into `UIStackView` the second `UILabel` is the same but embedded in another `UIView`:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I need `>=` constraint due to some more complex layout but I simplified the example. The labels should have the same position on the screen and the same width. But even in this example it causes random layout errors.

Tried to change priorities - it doesn't help. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Really difficult to help with the information you've provided. Tip: during layout development, give the labels / views / stackView contrasting background colors. That allows you to easily see the framing at runtime, and makes it much easier to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @DonMag in ohter words I need to have `UIStackView` with 2 labels which have equal width and which are not cut or have extra space independently from their values. And one of these labels is additionally emedded into `UIView`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a strange solution:

**Both labels should have "Content Hugging Priority" 750 (High) and "Content Compression Resistance Priority" 1000 (Required).**

If you do it your external stack view will be resized to the widest of 2 labels. And it looks workable even with multiline labels!